# benchmarks between multiple mysql queries and one single complex query

Tags: mysql

I was wondering whats the speed difference between multiple mysql queries and one single complex query? Is there a difference? Anyone have any benchmarks or tips?

Example

```
"SELECT *, ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT stuff) FROM stuff where stuff.id = id) as stuff, ( SELECT SUM(morestuff) FROM morestuff where morestuff.id = id) as morestuff, (SELECT COUNT(alotmorestuff) FROM alotmorestuff where alotmorestuff.id = id) as alotmorestuff FROM inventory, blah WHERE id=id"
```

vs single select queries for each.

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you at least give us some examples of what you're thinking of.

Comment: your query is incorrect, check your parenthesis please.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your complex query actually isn't. It's a bunch of independent selects mashed together which may or may not work - I see no reason there should be any noticeable difference. You may save a bit if you've got high latency connection to your db.

Comment: is your saying is that I am still making multiple queries not one query with my example?

Comment: Yes you are. To be honest I'm not even sure that query would work.